# What am I doing differently in these two cases?

Tags: r

I am trying to look at the difference in the scalings of the best and worst performing models generated in the following code. So far as I'm aware I treat the bc and oc cases the same (the code is copy-pasted with simple string replacement). Yet when I get to the last lines for the oc case, R says the dims are wrong. R is right, the lists of scalings aren't a list in the oc case, but rather a matrix whereas in the bc set they are a list. What am I doing that is leading to the bc and oc lists of scalings having different types? So far as I can tell the lists of lda results are the same type, and when I access the scalings manually they seem to be the same type in each case, but when I apply the same function to the lists of lda results withe the intent of getting the scalings as a list I get different types?

```
library("MASS")

all<-read.csv("~/Documents/All BC OC Data.csv")
filtered<-all[,apply(!is.na(all),2,all)]

bc.list.of.lists = list();

for(i in 1:500){
    bcnorm.orig <- subset(filtered,filtered$set %in% c('bc','normal'))
    c <-  nrow(bcnorm.orig[bcnorm.orig$set == 'bc',])
    c2 <-  nrow(bcnorm.orig)
    pis <- c(2+sample(c-2,(c-2)/3),c+sample(c2-c,(c2-c)/3))
    bcnorm <- bcnorm.orig[-pis,]
    sds <- sapply(bcnorm,sd)
    bcnorm <- bcnorm[,sds!=0]
    bcpredict <- bcnorm.orig[pis,sds!=0]
    sds <- sapply(bcpredict,sd)
    bcnorm <- bcnorm[,sds!=0]
    bcpredict <- bcpredict[,sds!=0]
    met.lda.bc <- lda(as.formula(paste("bcnorm$set ~ bcnorm$", paste(names(bcnorm)[-c(1,2)], collapse = " + bcnorm$"))))
    bcnorm <- bcpredict
    met.lda.bc.values.predicted <- predict(met.lda.bc, as.data.frame(scale(bcnorm[-c(1,2)])))
    wrong <- length(which(met.lda.bc.values.predicted$class != bcnorm$set))
    bc.list.of.lists[[i]] <- list(wrong=wrong, lda=met.lda.bc)
}
bc.errors<-sapply(bc.list.of.lists, "[[", "wrong")
bc.first<-bc.list.of.lists[order(bc.errors)][1:10]
bc.first.ldas<-sapply(bc.first, "[[", "lda")
bc.first.scalings<-apply(bc.first.ldas, 2,function(x)x$scaling)
bc.first.scalings<-lapply(bc.first.scalings,function(x)x[,1])

oc.list.of.lists = list();

for(i in 1:500){
    ocnorm.orig <- subset(filtered,filtered$set %in% c('oc','normal'))
    c <-  nrow(ocnorm.orig[ocnorm.orig$set == 'oc',])
    c2 <-  nrow(ocnorm.orig)
    pis <- c(2+sample(c-2,(c-2)/3),c+sample(c2-c,(c2-c)/3))
    ocnorm <- ocnorm.orig[-pis,]
    sds <- sapply(ocnorm,sd)
    ocnorm <- ocnorm[,sds!=0]
    ocpredict <- ocnorm.orig[pis,sds!=0]
    sds <- sapply(ocpredict,sd)
    ocnorm <- ocnorm[,sds!=0]
    ocpredict <- ocpredict[,sds!=0]
    met.lda.oc <- lda(as.formula(paste("ocnorm$set ~ ocnorm$", paste(names(ocnorm)[-c(1,2)], collapse = " + ocnorm$"))))
    ocnorm <- ocpredict
    met.lda.oc.values.predicted <- predict(met.lda.oc, as.data.frame(scale(ocnorm[-c(1,2)])))
    wrong <- length(which(met.lda.oc.values.predicted$class != ocnorm$set))
    oc.list.of.lists[[i]] <- list(wrong=wrong, lda=met.lda.oc)
}
oc.errors<-sapply(oc.list.of.lists, "[[", "wrong")
oc.first<-oc.list.of.lists[order(oc.errors)][1:10]
oc.first.ldas<-sapply(oc.first, "[[", "lda")
oc.first.scalings<-apply(oc.first.ldas, 2,function(x)x$scaling)
oc.first.scalings<-lapply(oc.first.scalings,function(x)x[,1])
```

Comment: Can you distill your problem down to a minimum? Have it reproducible as well?

Comment: That's as small as I can get it, and while it is reproducible (it happens every run) I can't provide the data for all sorts of reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the scalings were of different lengths in most cases, and so the lapply made lists then, and when they were all the same length it made matrices.

Really annoying and hard to track down behavior.